# Authenticate Grape 0.10.1 with doorkeeper 2.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, ruby-grape, doorkeeper

I'm using grape along with doorkeeper fro OAuth2 authentication. Now, I want to upgrade from grape 0.8 to grape 0.10.1, and doorkeeper to 2.0.1. Unfortunately, I ran into some problems. Before, I could use grape-doorkeeper to integrate doorkeeper easily in grape https://github.com/fuCtor/grape-doorkeeper

But after upgrading, I get some errors like `uninitialized constant Doorkeeper::DoorkeeperForBuilder (NameError)`, and also the `doorkeeper_for` helper seems to be removed from doorkeeper and replaced by `before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!` (see https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#backward-incompatible-changes).

Here https://github.com/intridea/grape#register-custom-middleware-for-authentication the Grape documentation tells us, that we can use `rack-oauth2` for OAuth2 authentication, but as far as I see, this lacks of the easy rails integration that doorkeeper provides, right?

So now, I'm a little bit confused, how to integrate doorkeeper 2.0.1 into grape 0.10.1. I already read some tutorials, but they are targeting older versions for this gems. So, any help is appreciated!

**Update**

I digged into the GrapeDoorkeeper gem, and found the following lines (https://github.com/fuCtor/grape-doorkeeper/blob/master/lib/grape-doorkeeper/oauth2.rb#L64):

`module OAuth2
    def doorkeeper_for *args
      doorkeeper_for = Doorkeeper::DoorkeeperForBuilder.create_doorkeeper_for(*args)
      use GrapeDoorkeeper::Middleware, doorkeeper: doorkeeper_for
    end
  end`

Then I looked into doorkeeper 2.0.1 and noticed, that the class `DoorkeeperForBuilder` and and the `create_doorkeeper_for` method are gone. I also couldn't find a replacement or another way to do this. To me, it looks like `Doorkeeper::DoorkeeperForBuilder.create_doorkeeper_for` returns a middleware that is used by grape. So, how would that be done with the new doorkeeper?

Another question would be, if this line still would work with doorkeeper 2: https://github.com/fuCtor/grape-doorkeeper/blob/master/lib/grape-doorkeeper/oauth2.rb#L73

`Grape::API.extend GrapeDoorkeeper::OAuth2`

Answer (score 0):

i recently moved from grape-doorkeeper to [wine_bouncer](https://github.com/antek-drzewiecki/wine_bouncer).
it works fine on ruby 2.2.0 and rails 4.2.0, with doorkeeper 2.0.1 and grape 0.10.1.